# Elif Condition in Python

Tags: python

I have some Python code which needs to take a string input from a text file named `varfile.txt` and conditions to be applied on that data and print the output. The code is as follows:

```
file = open("varfile.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
e= str(lines[1]);
print(e)
if  e == '<0.1%':
        print("1")
elif  e == '(0.1-25)%':
        print("2")
elif  e == '(0.25-0.5)%':
        print("3")
elif  e == '(0.5-1)%':
        print("4")
elif  e == '>1%':
        print("5")
else:
        print("0")
```

The ouput is as follows:

```
(0.25-0.5)%  
0
```

Even though `e` value is printed as `(0.25-0.5)%`, it is not comparing with the condition in the elif clause and giving `0` as an output though the output should be `3`. Could you please suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: PLS upload the input file

Comment: I think you are using an extra space on the elif condition. It should be e == '(0.25-0.5)%' not ' (0.25-0.5)%'

Comment: ya..that is fine, you can see that it is printing the right value but there is some error in comparison

Comment: Generally, each line ends in a newline character, so you should be testing for `e=='(0.25-0.5)%\n'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) `files.readlines()` does not strip the ending new line characters from the ends of the lines.

You can use `e.strip('\n')` to return a string with newlines removed, e.g.:

```
e = e.strip('\n')
if e == ...:
elif ...
```

Comment: I would recommend stripping all whitespace characters instead of only newlines before comparing, because files that users might change can easily contain spaces in the end of a line, which would else result in a hardly understandable error. So simply use `e.strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

`readlines` [includes the newline](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) character.